# Expression "That your work be perfect"

Tags: expressions

I frequently find this expression in literature and such. I couldn´t find anything on it on the net, only more of these expressions without explanations how to handle or understand them correctly:

"I have years of experience proofreading, editing and translating. From simple CVs and cover letters to Master Theses, it is important that your work **be** perfect and I will make sure that your end product is error-free."

Is that actually idiomatic language? Can it be replaced by "is"?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "subjunctive".

Comment: Probably a duplicate...

Comment: Formal English uses the bare infinitive, originally the present subjunctive, in subordinate clauses governed by certain verbs, as an indication that the clause being governed is not a statement of fact. This was inherited from ancient Proto-Indo-European. For example, Romance languages have stronger rules about these situations, and  with more obvious inflectional  morphologies, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you said "It is important that your work *is* perfect..." you'd have taken it out of subjunctive mode and the meaning would change: now it's about your value as an employee. Now your boss is saying that your work is perfect. If on the other hand he's making a demand, the word *that* introduces the subjunctive clause. So the verb should be *be*.